# types for tailwind css match Utilities and theme

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, tailwind-css

I am trying to use the Tailwind plugin but a TypeScript `error` popped up. What are the types of matchUtilities and themes?

```
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
const flattenColorPalette = require('tailwindcss/lib/util/flattenColorPalette')
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

type colo = ["wh","bla","ora","gra"];
const config: Config = {
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ matchUtilities, theme } : { matchUtilities : any, theme : any }) {
      matchUtilities(
        {
          'my-custom-class': (value : colo) => ({
              backgroundColor: value,
              color: theme('colors.white') 
          }),
        },
        { values: flattenColorPalette(theme('colors')) } 
      )
    }),
  ],
}
export default config
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is:

```
import type { PluginAPI } from "tailwindcss/types/config";
```

Answer (score 1):

if your tailwind file is in js you can use this,

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `PluginAPI` for the types of `matchUtilities` and `theme`.

Here is your example:

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
const flattenColorPalette = require('tailwindcss/lib/util/flattenColorPalette')
import type { PluginAPI } from "tailwindcss/types/config";

type colo = ["wh","bla","ora","gra"];
const config: Config = {
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ matchUtilities, theme } : { matchUtilities : PluginAPI["matchUtilities"], theme : PluginAPI["theme"] }) {
      matchUtilities(
        {
          'my-custom-class': (value : colo) => ({
              backgroundColor: value,
              color: theme('colors.white') 
          }),
        },
        { values: flattenColorPalette(theme('colors')) } 
      )
    }),
  ],
}
export default config
```