TS7031: Binding element addUtilities implicitly has an any type
I'm attempting to add some settings using addUtilities, but I keep encountering an error from TypeScript.
How can I get rid of it?


This answer looks like it might give you the types you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77730824/4529555

Following on from this answer, it seems the solution is to use the PluginAPI which provides you with the correct type. (Tailwind version 3.4.4)
import plugin from 'tailwindcss/plugin'
import type { PluginAPI, Config } from "tailwindcss/types/config";

const config: Config = {
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addUtilities }: { addUtilities: PluginAPI["addUtilities"] }) {
      addUtilities([])
    }),
  ],
  content: {
    files: []
  }
}
export default config;

